# Error con JavaFX al iniciar la aplicación

Tags: java, javafx

Al hacer esto me da un error:

```
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/sql/SQLException
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/alba1/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Prueba/target/classes/com/mycompany/prueba/primary.fxml
```

```
package com.mycompany.prueba;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * JavaFX App
 */
public class App extends Application {

    private static Scene scene;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        scene = new Scene(loadFXML("primary"), 640, 480);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    static void setRoot(String fxml) throws IOException {
        scene.setRoot(loadFXML(fxml));
    }

    private static Parent loadFXML(String fxml) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(App.class.getResource(fxml + ".fxml"));
        return fxmlLoader.load();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```

El archivo ***primary.fxml*** tiene este código:

```
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>

<VBox alignment="CENTER" fillWidth="false" nodeOrientation="LEFT_TO_RIGHT" prefHeight="765.0" prefWidth="934.0" spacing="20.0" style="-fx-background-color: #b0c2f2;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.mycompany.prueba.PrimaryController">
  <children>
     <ImageView fitHeight="283.0" fitWidth="247.0" preserveRatio="true">
        <image>
           <Image url="@../../../../../../../../../Desktop/Preogreso_donut/Captura.PNG" />
        </image>
     </ImageView>
     <Pane prefHeight="193.0" prefWidth="613.0">
        <children>
           <Label layoutX="101.0" layoutY="30.0" text="EMAIL">
              <font>
                 <Font name="Serif Regular" size="23.0" />
              </font>
           </Label>
           <Label layoutX="101.0" layoutY="70.0" text="Contraseña">
              <font>
                 <Font name="Serif Regular" size="23.0" />
              </font>
           </Label>
           <TextField fx:id="txtEmail" layoutX="250.0" layoutY="31.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="207.0" />
           <TextField fx:id="txtContrasena" layoutX="250.0" layoutY="71.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="207.0" />
           <Button fx:id="butAceptar" layoutX="398.0" layoutY="129.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onAceptar" style="-fx-background-color: #f2b0c2;" text="Aceptar">
              <font>
                 <Font name="Serif Regular" size="16.0" />
              </font>
           </Button>
           <Button fx:id="butCrearUser" layoutX="119.0" layoutY="129.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onCrearUsuario" style="-fx-background-color: #f2b0c2;" text="Crear usuario">
              <font>
                 <Font name="Serif Regular" size="16.0" />
              </font>
           </Button>
        </children>
     </Pane>
  </children>
  <padding>
     <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0" />
  </padding>
</VBox>
```

Comment: Según el error: *NoClassDefFoundError: java/sql/SQLException* en algún punto estás intentando usar una SQLException que tu código no puede encontrar entre sus paquetes importados. Estás usando algo de SQL? Porque en el código que indicas no veo nada raro, pero claro, la excepción indica -> *javafx.fxml.LoadException: /C:/Users/alba1/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Prueba/target/classes/com/mycompany/prueba/primary.fxml* Qué contiene ese archivo primary.fxml?

Comment: @Benito-B ya actualice la pregunta, deberias de poder ver el primary, y si estoy usando mysql con hibernate

Comment: Pues revisa todo bien, porque en algún sitio estás intentando usar una sqlexception que no has importado, parece ser. No puedo verla en el código que has mostrado, pero debería estar

Comment: Probablemente lo que te está pasando es que Hibernate necesite lanzar una excepción de ese tipo (`java.sql.SQLException`) pero no encuentra la clase en el classpath o modulepath. Dado que esa clase es del core de Java quiero pensar que tu aplicación hace uso del sistema de módulos de Java pero en el descriptor del módulo (archivo module-info.java) no has declarado el `requires` correspondiente. Si es así prueba agregando esto al archivo module-info.java: `requieres java.sql;`.

Comment: @E.Betanzos acabo de probar lo que me dijiste y ese era el problema, gracias

Comment: Me alegro que te haya funcionado!